# Unable to send link in an email using mailgun in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, mailgun

I'm using mailgun to send emails to users,and i also want to share a hyperlink in that email using express.js,below is an sample code

```
let HtmlLink = `<a href="http://00.00.0.83:3000/user/v1/resetPassword/${token}">here</a>`;
var message = {
  subject: 'Forgot Account Link',
  html: HtmlLink
}

try {
  const recipient = results[0].emailId;
  console.log("emailId RESC:" + recipient)
  await sendEmail(recipient, message);
} catch (err) {
  console.log("ERROR::" + err)
  res.json({
    "status": 403,
    "message": "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR",
    "data": [err]
  });
}
res.json({ message: 'Your query has been sent' });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is okay the way it is, just you have a wrong character in HtmlLink (' after href). Try

```
 let HtmlLink = `<a href="http://00.00.0.83:3000/user/v1/resetPassword/${token}">here</a>`
```

Comment: Still not working,getting text only and not an hyperlink

Comment: Check out my sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/mailgun-send-link-so-eh010. Could there be something you are missing

Comment: Thanks for the code,It's working fine in mailinator,but for gmail its showing text like        "<a href="http://00.00.0.83:3000/user/v1/resetPassword/12344">here</a>"

Comment: Try enclosing your link in html body

Comment: now getting result like"<html><a href="http://00.00.0.83:3000/user/v1/resetPassword/12344">here</a></html>
"

Comment: Use this <html><body><a href="http://00.00.0.83:3000/user/v1/resetPassword/${token}">here</a></body></html>

Comment: Can we check your codes together, we may spot something

Comment: Can you help me with this QS : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064535/unable-to-fetch-html-hidden-input-values-into-express-app?noredirect=1