# Unable to fetch html hidden input values into express app

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm trying to fetch some hidden form values in post route of my express app,but getting undefined objects in post route,below is some code snippet

```
const express = require("express")
const app   =   express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Authentication service started on port 3000');
});

app.get("/link",(req,res)=>{
    let token = 124578
   let link="http://"+req.get('host')+"/postmethod";
    console.log("hyperlink:"+link)
    let formHtmlPostLink="<form method='post' action='"+link+"'>    <input type='hidden' name='bearer' value='"+token+"'> <input type='hidden' name='test' value='test'> <button type='submit' name='submit_param' value='submit_value' class='link-button'>      Reset Password         </button>       </form>"
    res.send(formHtmlPostLink)
})
app.post("/postmethod",(req,res)=>{
    res.send(req.body)//undefined objects
})
```

Comment: Can you add your frontend code?

Comment: As of now I've not included any front end code,I'm using this html form in nodemailer to send email with link to next post router

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to submit form to `/postmethod`, add middleware `bodyParser.urlencoded()`

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
```

If form is not being submitted, change link to relative url

```
  let link = "/postmethod";
```

Check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-hidden-form-inputs-wycgr)